# Filter similar JSON keys and compare using Lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript

Trying to filter `localJSON` based on `remoteJSON` and create a new `localJSONFiltered` based on those keys present in the `remoteJSON`. And then finally comparing the values.

Script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**remoteJSON data.** and **localJSON**

```
const remoteJSON = {"address": "LAN",
                    "city": "LAN-CITY",
                    "code": "A1"       
                    };

const localJSON = { "city": "LAN-CITY",
                    "code": "A1",
                    "address": "LAN",
                    "extraKey":"I am not required..please remove me while comparing"
                   }
              
console.log( _.isEqual(a, b) ); // false
```

Expecting to remove the `extraKey` property from the localJSON i.e., localJSON need to have only those properties which is in `remoteJSON` and then compare the values.

```
const remoteJSON = {"address": "LAN",
                    "city": "LAN-CITY",
                    "code": "A1"       
                    };
const localJSONRemoving = _.omit(localJSON, ['extraKey']));
const localJSONAfterRemoving = { "city": "LAN-CITY",
                    "code": "A1",
                    "address": "LAN"
                   }
              
console.log( _.isEqual(a, b) ); // true
```

My localJSON has over 30 properties. So hardcoding all the properties looks bad.

Comment: Lodash has [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) or you could potentially customize the comparison using [isEqualWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith).

Comment: localJSON has over 30 elements and remoteJSON has over 20 properties. Hard coding those 10 properties using Omit can resolve the problem. But that is not the reason why I posted this question, I am expecting a smarter approach from smarter guys out there.

Comment: The smarter guys at Stack Overflow don't write people's code for them ;-) Options include finding the intersection of object keys e.g. `_.intersection(_.keys(a), _.keys(b))`, keeping it in the lodash family.

Comment: @honeysingh You could also use [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) instead of `_.omit()` that way you only have to specify the 3 properties you want to compare.

Comment: @jarmod i think I need something which would give me an array of those properties that need to be eliminated. So that I can use Omit to remove those from localJSON. However  _.intersection(_.keys(a), _kys(b)) return an array of required elements. So do you have any such prop which gives me ```address``` property.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I have over 30 properties to specify. .

Comment: Yes, you'll need to exclude the undesirable keys e.g. `_.filter(_.keys(b), (x) => !_.keys(a).includes(x))`

Comment: Yes that worked. Finally you are the smart guy i was searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, continuing the use of lodash:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const a = {
  address: "LAN",
  city: "LAN-CITY",
  code: "A1"
};

const b = {
  city: "LAN-CITY",
  code: "A1",
  address: "LAN",
  extraKey: "I am not required..please remove me while comparing",
};

// Goal: test if a and b are the same except that we ignore extra keys in b

const extraKeys = _.filter(_.keys(b), (x) => !_.keys(a).includes(x));
console.log(_.isEqual(a, _.omit(b, extraKeys)));
```

Comment: Alternatively you could also select the keys from `a` out of `b`. `_.isEqual(a, _.pick(_.keys(a), b))`

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes, that's a better solution but with the parameters reversed, so: `_.isEqual(a, _.pick(b, _.keys(a)))` presumably.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Been working too much with functional languages. There the subject mostly goes last.